# Why this char array was changed after some in-relatived code executed?

Tags: c, arrays, string

There is a function convert a char array to a char array at first:

```
char *tohex(char bnyin[32]) {

    static char hexout[8];
    ....
    return hexout;
}



char hex[8]   = "00000000";
char bny[32]  = "00000000000000000000000000000000";
int num = 20;
int remap_bf[21];

for (i=0;i<num;i++)
{
    bny[remap_bf[i]]='1';
}

strncpy(hex, tohex(bny),8);
printf("%s", hex);
printf("\n");
```

I can print out correct result about char hex at this moment, but after that,

```
int bkn[8];
int bfn[8];
int num = 20;

for (i=0;i<num;i++) {
    bkn[i] = remap_bf[i] / 8;
    bfn[i] = remap_bf[i] % 8;
}

printf("%s", hex);
printf("\n");
```

While this time it just prints nothing or weird character. Since the second part of code does not affect the hex array, why it got lost? What's interesting, when the num is 8, both prints looks correct, but when the num goes to 20, the second print gets nothing.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten that strings in C need a terminator. So a string of eight characters actually needs an array of nine characters to fit the terminator. Without the terminator all string functions will cause *undefined behavior* as they go out of bounds looking for the terminator. That includes printing them.

Comment: Also, you *do* initialize e.g. `remap_bf` somewhere before the loops using it?

Comment: Lastly, you go out of bounds when writing to the `bkn` and `bfn` arrays. Again leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: regarding this code block: `for (i=0;i<num;i++)
{
    bny[remap_bf[i]]='1';
}`   the elements of array `remap_bf[]` are not initialized, so can have any value from -2gig to +2gig  so will (most likely) result in accessing memory that is WAY outside the bounds of the array `bny[]`  That is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: a large amount of the posted code is not inside any function, so will not compile.  Please add an edit that posts the actual code

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry I forgot to mention that remap_bf is initialized somewhere else. remap_bf contains #num random integers from 0 to 19. When num = 8, both prints got correct results, but when num = 20, only the first print gets fffff000. I also tried to make char hex[9] but the result are same.

Comment: @user3629249 Sorry I forgot to mention that remap_bf is initialized somewhere else. remap_bf contains #num random integers from 0 to 19. When num = 8, both prints got correct results, but when num = 20, only the first print gets fffff000. I also tried to make char hex[9] but the result are same.

Comment: Strongly suggest passing the actual code as the currently posted code does not contain all the relevant details.